# tuple error C2661 in while creating thread using abstract class member c++

Tags: c++

error C2661:  'std::tuple::tuple': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments

I have created an abstract class called DataManager and it has a  pure virtual funnction close(ClientData  b) =0 ;

```
ifndef _DataManager_HPP_
#define _DataManager_HPP_
#include <string>
#include "../ClientBlockData.hpp"


namespace slssm {

enum COMMAND_TYPE { DB_WRITE = 0, DB_READ, DB_NONE };
class DataManager {
  public:

    virtual std::vector<std::string> Update(ClientBlockData& blkData,
                                            std::string& iQuery) = 0;

    virtual void closeDb(ClientBlockData& blkData) = 0;

    virtual std::string buildDbQuery(std::string& iTableName,
                                     std::string& msg,
                                     std::string& oTopic,
                                     COMMAND_TYPE& oCmdType) = 0;
   // ~DataManager() {}
};
```

which as a dervied class SQLiteManager in SQLiteManager.hpp

```
void closeDb(ClientBlockData& blkData) {
mDb=nullptr;
}
```

in the main function I use it like this

```
SQLiteManager* dbmang = new SQLiteManager(blkData.mDb, mTableName, iSSMLoggingFlag, qcc);

// Spawn a new listener thread that responds to queries
mQueryHandlerThreads[blkData.mLocalId] =
    std::thread(&SQLiteManager::closeDb, dbmang,
                blkData);
```

The reported error

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\memory(2539,1): error C2661:  'std::tuple<void (__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager *,slssm::ClientBlockData>::tuple': no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\thread(49): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager *,slssm::ClientBlockData>,std::default_delete<_Ty>> std::make_unique<std::tuple<void (__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager *,slssm::ClientBlockData>,void(__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager*&,slssm::ClientBlockData&,0>(void (__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* &&)(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager *&,slssm::ClientBlockData &)' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\thread(49): message :         with
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\thread(49): message :         [
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\thread(49): message :             _Ty=std::tuple<void (__cdecl slssm::SQLiteManager::* )(slssm::ClientBlockData &),slssm::SQLiteManager *,slssm::ClientBlockData>
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\thread(49): message :         ]
```

Comment: Try with `std::ref(blkData)` passed to `std::thread` ctor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the reference to blkData

```
   mQueryHandlerThreads[blkData.mLocalId] =
        std::thread(&SQLiteManager::closeDb, dbmang,
                    std::ref(blkData));
```

Comment: Please explain not just "how" or "what" to do, but also "why". That is much more helpful, for the OP as well as future readers.